# RavenDB failover scenario. How to know the actual server?

Tags: ravendb, database-replication, failover

I'm setting up a project with replication and failover for RavenDB (server and client 3.0), and now I'm testing with a replica DB.

The failover behavior is very simple: I've two servers, one on 8080 and one on 8081. The configuration is basically this:

```
store.FailoverServers.ForDatabases = new Dictionary<string, ReplicationDestination[]>
{
    {
        "MyDB",
        new[]
            {
                new ReplicationDestination
                    {
                        Url = "http://localhost:8080"
                    },
                new ReplicationDestination
                    {
                        Url = "http://localhost:8081"
                    }
            }
    }
};
```

The failover IS working well, I've tried to shut down the first server (that is the one used in the DocumentStore configuration) and the second one is responding as expected.

What I want to know is: is there a way to understand what is the current failover server that is responding to the queries? If inside the session I try to navigate the DocumentSession properties (as the session.Advanced.DocumentStore.Identifier) I cannot find references to the second server, but I see only reference to the first one, that is the one used for the configuration.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ReplicationInformer.FailoverStatusChanged` to get notified on failovers.

You can access the replication informer using: `DocumentStore.GetReplicationInformerForDatabase()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ayende, I'm trying that, but as I can see from the ReplicationInformer I don't have a simple information on what is the actual server(s) in use, I only get a failureCounts for the servers who fails. Is that correct? Also on ReplicationDestinations I see only the secondary server (even when it's down).

Comment: You get the replication destinations to know the secondaries, and the primary is whatever is defined on the store. Then you can get whatever we'll be using this node using the `ShouldExecuteUsing` method.